# How can I use Selenium to scroll within a Javascript applet embedded inside a page with no html-accessible scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium, scroll

[image: See screenshot to understand the context.]

Dear smart humans,

I am attempting to get Selenium to select a series of 15 checkboxes, however, only the first eight are visible before scrolling is necessary.

I am trying with no luck to get Selenium to scroll within this dynamically generated JavaScript window embedded into a webpage. The problem is that the inner window's scrollbar doesn't have any html representation, because it is an object within an embedded applet.

No `scrollIntoView()` type solution has worked, because the checkboxes don't exist before they are dynamically loaded once scrolling happens.

The way that a human user would scroll the inner window would be either by:

- Focusing the cursor in the inner window and scrolling the mouse wheel down
- Clicking and holding on the down arrow in the embedded scrollbar (which has no html representation)
- Dragging the embedded scrollbar (which has no html representation) downwards

I have tried using `JavascriptExecutor` solutions such as `scrollTo`, `scrollBy` and `scrollTop` with no luck.

I have tried workarounds such as:

- A method to invoke keypresses such as `ARROW_DOWN`, `PAGE_DOWN` and `ENTER` in various combinations. Had partial success on various machines, but nothing reliable:

```
public static void simulateScrolling(Actions action) {

    //example code, there were a few variations
    action.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
    action.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
    action.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();

    //wait for the next button to buffer
    try {
        Thread.sleep(300);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

- Using Java's `Robot` to get the mouse to scroll using the `mouseWheel()` method after moving the cursor to focus over the inner window, with no success:

```
Robot rob = new Robot();
rob.mouseMove(driver.findElement(By.id(checkboxId)).getLocation().getX(),driver.findElement(By.id(checkboxId)).getLocation().getY());
rob.delay(750);
rob.mouseWheel(200);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check with "scrollBy"?

Comment: Update the question with your code trials

Comment: @Piyush yes I did with no luck unfortunately

Comment: Any help with this? Still stuck..